# confusion over which relationship to use in models for these two tables

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a user table that consists of these columns:

```
| id | username | password | email | pants_size_id | shirt_size_id |
```

`pants_size_id` and `shirt_size_id` are filled with foreign tables id keys where I store a list of sizes for pants and shirts in different country specific measures, example of `pants_size` table:

```
| id | UK_sizing | US_sizing | IT_sizing |
```

a single user will have only one pants and shirt size so the user table is filled with the ID of the corresponding rows in the size tables.

what kind of relationship does this imply between the user model and the pants and shirt sizing models?

Also how can I retrieve the data inside the foreign table column (example IT_sizing) when returning auth user `return \Auth::user();` instead of the numeric size_id ?

In other words how can I retrieve say '32' (a pants size) instead of the `pants_size_id` (let's say '1').

Comment: Pretty sure you want to put in a `hasOne` relationship for both `pants_size` and `shirt_size` in the `user` table.  Then access it like so: `$user->pants_size->UK_sizing`

Comment: @CatoMinor Looks like what the OP wants. Write that as an answer so he can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cato has the right answer, I can't exactly respond to it because of my rep but the logic in your other answer doesn't make sense from a relational standpoint.

Users don't belong to a size, instead, Users have a size.

To me it sounds like you mixed up the foreign and local key assignment it should be User->hasOne(pants_size).

In your model it would be the following, the explicitness of the keys isn't great, but if you have some weird thing laravel can't figure out this should work.

```
public function pants_size(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Pants_size','id','pants_size_id');

}

public function shirt_size(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Shirt_size','id','shirt_size_id');
}
```

To answer the other question of how to find the size (32), since you're dealing with three different measurements you have to have a where clause on the specific measurement the 32 represents, and get the id. If you specifically wanted the users you would call the eloquent query as so:

```
\Auth::User()->pants_size()->(..whatever measurement you want..)
```

Comment: I tried like you said with `return $this->hasOne('App\Pants_size','id','pants_size_id');` .. doesn't work. Actually a user can belong to a size from my point of view. Many users belong to a size really. Example 100 users are in the group of users that have a pants_size 32.

Comment: From the way you're wanting to query a User has a size rather than belonging to a size. If you're trying to find all users that *have* a pants_size of 32 then you already explained the relationship is a *has*.

What error is it returning because if the tables are defined as you explain then it should work.

Comment: please consider that the pants_size table doesn't have a user_id column. It only acts as a container for the various sizes and is limited, example 20 rows. So based on documentation the hasOne relationship looks for a user_id column in the pants_size table but that could work if the table contained many data about single users (example 100 users 100 sizes)

Comment: However you have your models setup is wrong then. The code I gave doesn't have it looking for user_id, it has the *pants_size_id* being the local key (the one in the users table) and *id* being the foreign key (the one in the pants_size) table. The inverse relation for the size to users is belongsToMany.

Comment: I tried again and modified like you suggested. Now it's working. The difference in sql query is like this: with my solution: `"select * from 'users' where 'users'.'id' = ? - "select * from 'pants_size' where 'pants_size'.'id' = ? limit 1"` with yours: `"select * from 'users' where 'users'.'id' = ? limit 1" - "select * from 'pants_size' where 'pants_size'.'id' = ? and 'pants_size'.'id' is not null limit 1"` so the latter only adds a check to see if id is not null but how could it be null? The data is required during registration.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it's just a safety check. I don't know all of the reasons why but I'm sure Taylor had a good reason. If it's working now, would you mind marking my answer as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `function` establishing a `hasOne` relationship for both `pants_size` and `shirt_size` in the `user` model.  Be sure to set the `foreign key` and `local key` correctly if you don't want Laravel to assume default keys ([see here for details](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)).

Once the `functions` are created, you will be able to obtain data about the user's size information like so: `App\Model\User::find(123)->pants_size->UK_sizing`.  (This example is for a user with ID of 123).

Comment: actually it doesn't work. the sql generated by this solution is: `SQL: select * from 'pants_size' where 'pants_size'.'user_id' = 1 and 'pants_size'.'user_id' is not null limit 1` but as I explained there is not any  `user_id ` column in  `pants_size `

Comment: For anyone who is concerned that this answer may be wrong, please see the answer provided by Sieabah which confirms that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I made it work:

in USER model:

```
   public function pants_size(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Pants_size');

        }

        public function shirt_size(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Shirt_size');
        }
```

In Pants_size and Shirt_size Models:

```
public function user(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\User');

    }
```

That last one works also with hasOne.

The code I use to retrieve the data is:

```
public function index()
    {

        echo $user = User::find($id);

        echo $pants = User::find($id)->pants_size->it_sizing;

        echo $shirt = User::find($id)->shirt_size->it_sizing;

    }
```